# How to make a color picker SeekBar programmatically

Tags: android, seekbar, color-picker

Android studio how to creat color picker like this?

[image]

Comment: what have you done so far ? show a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one library like this

[Color Picker](https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference)

And remove everything, keeping only the seek bar for the hue value.